# transfering compositing nodes with render layer nodes

Tags: rendering, node-editor, render-layers, compositing-nodes, append

I have two projects. In one I have a lot of compositing nodes including a lot of render layer nodes. I have found a way to append nodes but it does not work with render layer nodes. Is there a way to append compositing nodes including the render layer ones? It would take me ages to copy that and yet it would not be the same.
Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Append a Scene

Compositor nodes belong to the Scene settings.

You just have to Append a Scene from a blendile containing the compositor setup you want. Go under -> File -> Append, pick the file and look under the Scene folder.

[image]

Then go to the scene selector, open the compositor in the appended one and copy past the nodes in yours.

[image]

Remember to update the render layer input scene in the copied compositor node setup.

[image]

Comment: @user115148 does this help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did append files from the scene folder,. There are 3 files:  _mainScene, dustParticules, and volumeLight. I did try to append just _mainScene and since it did nothing I also tried to append all of those. (The blender just freezes for few seconds and then nothing happens) But nothing happened. The compositor nodes did not change at all. Do you know what could be the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Once you append a scene. you should find the scene in the scene in the scene selector. I've added some lines to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I did copy the node, then changed the scene to the one I want the nodes to be in. But when I wanted to render it, it rendered the scene from the second project. Even though I had the scene I wanted to render selected.

Comment: We are almost there. In the compositor you have to update the Render Layer Scene to use. Also, after copying the nodes, remember to delete the scene you appended, or your file will increase it's size.